# How to dynamically load a text into a user control label in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I want to load 2 user controls(same but with different text property).
My user control consists of a label with a Function defined for text in ascx.cs

i am loading the control at run time using a panel ..here i want both the user control label to have different texts.

My .ascx file

```
 <asp:Label ID="uclbl" runat="server" />
```

My .ascx.cs file

```
 public string textforlabel
    {
        get { return uclbl.Text; }
        set { uclbl.Text = value; }
    }
```

My .aspx file

```
  <asp:Panel ID="panelMain" runat="server" >
   </asp:Panel>
```

* i have registered the the control

My .aspx.cs file

```
Control _dummyUserControl = (Control)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControl/User1.ascx");
        _dummyUserControl.  ; //can not find the textforlabel here
        panelMain.Controls.Add(_dummyUserControl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are making incorrect casting, you should cast to your user control type :

```
User1 _dummyUserControl = (User1)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControl/User1.ascx");
 _dummyUserControl.MyProperty = "SDfsdf"  ; //here you can find all your custom properties
panelMain.Controls.Add(_dummyUserControl);
```

Comment: You beated me 4 seconds. ;)

Comment: :D :D :D i think he wont believe such fast answering

Comment: I didn't know that we have to typecast it...although very easy solution...u guys answered with a lightening speed XD.
NOTE: i needed to add a "using.ProjectName.UserControl"

Answer (score 0):

You have to type cast:

```
User1 _dummyUserControl = (User1)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControl/User1.ascx");
```